# replicate what the back button on the browser does... EXACTLY

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, model-view-controller

as the title suggests, I'd like to click on something on my website, and have it do EXACTLY the same thing as the back button.

I have tried window.history.go(-1) which seems to be going back 2 pages as opposed to 1 on all browsers except firefox where it seems to work.

The back button on any browser at all, does exactly what I want. returns to the previous page, showing the same page data from before. Any ideas why window.history.go(-1) would go back twice, and any idea if there is another way that mimics the back button EXACTLY?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant code of the pages to get a context.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.history.back();`

[See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but no joy. Also goes back 2 pages.

Comment: Interesting. Can you put a JS alert in the function to see if it is being triggered twice?

Comment: I've tried that just now and same thing. Alert appears once, page goes back twice. To note: it's not going back once, then once again, it's simply jumping b ack two pages in a oner.

Comment: Can I provide any more context that may help? i.e. this is a "go back to search results" I am trying to achieve, and it's actually going back to the search page itself, I feel like it might be struggling to reload the search results and so just going back a step further. However, the back button itself works 100% correctly. I'm using MVC

Comment: Is the "Search results" section an actual separate page? Or is it just dynamically loaded in content from the "search" page?

Comment: it's a separate page. here's how the url's are:

/property/search/   -->   /property/search/results   -->  /property/details/{id}

the link to go back is on the /details/{id} page and skips straight back to property/search/   leaving out the results part.

To test, I've tried the same code on other more straightforward parts of the site and it does the same thing there.

Comment: Could you try redirecting to the page's absolute URL via JS, just to test?

Comment: that works beautifully. I am still baffled. I used 

            $('.go-back').click(function () {
                document.location.href = "http://localhost:56075/property/search/results";
            });

Comment: How is it that the user navigates to the results page?

I.e. do you use some JS to send them from the search page to the results page?

I think that the results page isn't being saved in the history for some reason.

Comment: It's an MVC form that takes them from search page to results page. I'd tend to agree with you there, however when using the actual back button on the browser it works without fail every single time, so it must be in history?

I've noticed the following:

document.location.href = "/property/search/results";
works on chrome,  but not firefox or i.e.

window.history.go(-1);  /  
works on firefox, but not chrome or i.e.